# PayPal Android SDK keeps on "checking my device"

Tags: android, paypal, sdk

I am trying to use the PayPal Android SDK (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) in my App. I used the same methods like their example. All parameters like ClientID are the correct ones from my PayPal sandbox. When I press the button that calls the PayPal activity, a screen captioned "Checking this device...", a spinning ProgressBar  and a PayPal Logo appears on the screen. I let this screen like this for hours, but nothing happend. 
Thanks for help and excuse me for my bad english, it's my first question here and I am from Germany...

There is now output in LogCat From PayPal or its Activity. Here is my code:

```
  package de.jimpachnet.xaver;






import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.json.JSONException;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class Premium extends Activity {


private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;

// note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
// when testing in sandbox, this is likely the -facilitator email address. 
private static final String CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "XXXXXXXXX-facilitator@t-online.de"; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_premium);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);

    startService(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.premium, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onButtonPayPal (View view) {
    onBuyPressed();
}


public void onBuyPressed() {
    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("2.11"), "USD", "StXaverAppPremiumAccount");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);


    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "test");
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "Nope");
    }
    else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
    }
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: We cant help you here until you paste your LogCat.Just by reading the above description.Can get much out of it.Check out this tutorial http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/10/paypal-android-sdk-with-multiple-in-app.html

Comment: Thank you, I have added my code, but LogCat doesn't provide any output from PayPal...

Comment: Is logcat shows some output of other code?

Comment: No, just my System.out strings. but when I cancel the PayPal Screen after some hours, I get his appears in LogCat, I don't know if this is useful: http://www.loaditup.de/files/806227_5b3yrevu6e.png

Comment: I will investigate this issue but a new major release of the PayPal Android SDK shipped this past Monday.  There are minor integration changes.  Could you move to that release and try again?  The LogCat helps but would be even better if the Time column was included.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the new SDK.

Comment: Great - let us know how that goes for you.